# Upper-bound for the max eigenvalue of a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Given a symmetric matrix $A$ with positive entries $a_{ij}>0$, then can I say that $\lambda_{max}(A)\le \lambda_{max}(B)$ where $B$ is a matrix with all entries being $b_{ij}=b=\max\limits_{i,j}\{a_{ij}\}$. If so, we can say that $\lambda_{max}(A)\le nb$?

Comment: Yes. Try a search for Perron-Frobenius theory.